Custom color for unbrushed areas in D3 graphs (Angular)
I want to apply some color for brushed part and some color for non brushed areas in d3 charts.
  const brush = d3.brush()
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('start', brushstart)
  .on('end', brushed);

  svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'brush')
  .call(brush)

 function brushstart() {
   const brushSelection = svg.select('.brush .selection');
   brushSelection.attr('fill', 'orange')
 }

by this method I can be able to set colors for brushed part, how can I achieve the same for unbrushed areas.

You can do it very similar to your brushed part.


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg width="400" height="400" id="drawing"></svg>
    <script>
      const brush = d3
        .brush()
        .extent([
          [0, 0],
          [400, 400],
        ])
        .on('start', brushstart);
      //.on('end', brushed);

      var svg = d3.select('#drawing').append('svg');

      svg.append('g').attr('class', 'brush').call(brush);

      svg
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 200)
        .attr('cy', 200)
        .attr('r', 40)
        .attr('fill', 'red');

      function brushstart() {
        const overlaySelection = svg.select('.brush .overlay');
        overlaySelection.attr('fill', 'steelblue');
        overlaySelection.attr('fill-opacity', 0.3);

        const brushSelection = svg.select('.brush .selection');
        brushSelection.attr('fill', 'orange');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



